# Run an application in the background and detect whenever the screen in double tapped

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I make an application run in background and detect whenever the user is double tapping so I can respond back?

Comment: last press - current press

Comment: I've overrided the tapping functions but these things are available only in my application , not in the whole phone.

Comment: so if the user double taps in another app, you want your app to respond?  That seems like a horrible design.

Comment: yes..and I'm not going to release the app..its just for me. the back button on my phone is not working(display is broken...everything works but the buttons are not )

Answer (score 2):

If your application is not running in the foreground you can't catch tap-events. That's basically the difference between background and foreground.

Comment: Thanks but how I'm supposed to do that? Is there any documentation or something I should read for making an idea about the way of doing this?

Comment: Foreground is your normal application. You cannot have an extra process running in the foreground, nor can you catch events outside of your own application pages. Simply put, what you want to do is impossible.